# Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2021

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: DevOps Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://devops.stackexchange.com/election/2) on **April 26** to bring in two more moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on April 26, users can [nominate themselves](https://devops.stackexchange.com/election/2).Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the `discussion` and `election` tags.)
- On May 3, if there are three or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-moderator-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-pa), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on May 11.

(Note for current moderators: there's no need to nominate yourself even though you'll likely get an email saying you should. The system assumes the first election is a graduation election, which would mean moderators would need to be re-elected. This isn't that sort of election.)

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.

Comment: That's a bit strange to have a "pro tempore" election. I mean, the people gets elected, that's no more a temporary role until election takes place, right? I very well know the pro temp. has no expiration date at all as former mod here, but it makes things blury, would elected mods need to run again in case of site graduation ?